# Value of type 'X' has no member 'y' - optional func in protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to get a better understanding of protocols in Swift. Specifically optional protocol methods. I thought the issue might have to do with my protocol being defined / used in a different file, but if you put the following in a playground you'll get the same issue:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    optional func shouldJump() -> Bool
}

extension NSObject : MyProtocol {}

class Test {
    func testJump() {
        let object = NSObject()
        let jump = object.shouldJump?() ?? true

        print("should jump: \(jump)")
    }
}

let t = Test()
t.testJump()
```

Here is the error message:

```
error: value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'shouldJump'
            let jump = object.shouldJump?() ?? true
                       ^~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~
```

For some reason it doesn't accept that the protocol has been defined on NSObject. Code completion finds it, but the compiler doesn't let it pass.

I'm not sure if my `?? true` part will work, but I want that to be a default value incase the method isn't defined.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the compiler knowns NSObject doesn't have `shouldJump` method, so the call `object.shouldJump?()` makes no sense. You can cast `object` to your protocol:

```
let jump = (object as MyProtocol).shouldJump?() ?? true
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `NSObject` conforms to `MyProtocol`, but because it doesn't implement the optional protocol method, the compiler knows it does not have the `Selector` `shouldJump`:

```
let object = NSObject()
object.conformsToProtocol(MyProtocol) // true
object.respondsToSelector("shouldJump") // false
```

One way to solve this is to implement the protocol method in the extension in order for the object to perform that selector:

```
extension NSObject : MyProtocol {
    func shouldJump() -> Bool {
        // some logic here
        return true
    }
}

class Test {
    func testJump() {
        let object = NSObject()

        let jump = object.shouldJump()

        print("should jump: \(jump)")
    }
}

let t = Test()
t.testJump() // works
```

If you don't want to implement the optional method in the extension, you have to cast your `NSObject` as `MyProtocol` and verify that it responds to the optional `Selector`:

```
class Test {
    func testJump() {
        let object = NSObject()

        let obj = object as MyProtocol

        if object.respondsToSelector("shouldJump")  {
            let jump = obj.shouldJump?()

            print("should jump: \(jump)")
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }


    }
}
```

You can also skip the `respondsToSelector` step and use an `if let` or `guard` to verify that `shouldJump()` returns non-nil.

```
class Test {
    func testJump() {
        let object = NSObject()

        guard let obj: MyProtocol = object else {
            return // object does not conform to MyProtocol
        }

        if let jump = obj.shouldJump?() { // if shouldJump() returns non-nil
            print("should jump: \(jump)")
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As of Xcode Version 7.3 beta (7D152p), using string literals as the selector is deprecated.  The equivalent call is now object.respondsToSelector(#selector(MyProtocol.shouldJump)).

Comment: @PriceRingo Thanks, I'm not using the beta yet, so I haven't implemented this change.  When this is required by the latest stable version of Xcode, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Would you mind writing the code for your last option, too? As someone with years of Objective-C under me but not much Swift yet, this seems like the most interesting approach. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher Sure thing, I'll update this when I get back to my computer tomorrow (on mobile now).

Comment: @StevenFisher updated my answer to include Swift code for the last option.

Comment: Thanks so much. Also, who the hell would down vote that?

Answer (score 1):

Swift is a type safe language. In order to be able to use `shouldJump?()` you first must have an object conformant to `MyProtocol`. In this case you can simply cast your type:

```
let jump = (object as MyProtocol).shouldJump?() ?? true
```

You can also store it in a variable:

```
let jumper = object as MyProtocol
let jump = jumper?.shouldJump() ?? true
```